# Return HTML string from ServiceStack cached set using .ToOptimizedResultUsingCache()

Tags: caching, angularjs, servicestack, angularjs-directive

The cached response returns with all quotes escaped and \n characters added.  The resulting string is also wrapped in quotes.  When not cached, the html is returned just fine.  How do I get past this?  I am using angularjs on the client to make the API request and set the returned value to the $.html() of a div.

```
if (enableCaching)
{
    var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<ContentValueRequest>(Request.Group, Request.Key);
    var expireInTimespan = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

    return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, cacheKey, expireInTimespan, () => {
        return GetContentValueRequest(Request);
    });
}
else
    return GetContentValueRequest(Request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I have all the context/code to answer the question but the below code seems to work for me. If `?formt=html` is not included in the ServiceStack request url it will return a JSON string and the quotes are escaped and \n characters added.

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="testApp">

    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">

        <p>Write Contents Below:</p>

        <div id="writeHere"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Angular code**

```
angular.module('testApp', [], function () {

})
.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    var req = $http.get('/api/CacheTest?format=html');
    req.success(function (data) {
        $('#writeHere').html(data);
    });
    req.error(function (data) {
        $('#writeHere').html('Error');
    });

});
```

**Request & Service**

```
[Route("/CacheTest")]
public class ContentValueRequest
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class CacheService : Service
{
    public object Get(ContentValueRequest Request)
    {
        var enableCaching = true;
        if (enableCaching)
        {
            var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<ContentValueRequest>("someKey");
            var expireInTimespan = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

            return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, cacheKey, expireInTimespan, () =>
            {
                return GetContentValueRequest(Request);
            });
        }
        else
            return GetContentValueRequest(Request);
    }

    private string GetContentValueRequest(ContentValueRequest request)
    {
        var ret = @"<em>""Quoted Text"", <em>Bold</em>" + Environment.NewLine;
        ret += @"A second line.";
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  I will test that and give you credit if it works on my end.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I would like to return HTML within the JSON, and it typically works with a custom response object, but doesn't seem to work with a single string (html) value.

Comment: I think this is the issue https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-return-types#different-return-types. Returning a String (type) is written directly to the Response Stream so the is no serialization happening.